# Are 3DS eshop games console bound?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id, nintendo-eshop

I got an used 3DS, and it came with 2 EShop games (Pokemon OR and DK Returns), the thing is, the old owner's account is still logged in and I lost all the contact info with him. My question is, if I format the console and log in with my Nintendo ID account, will I still be able to download the games it had installed? I saw some people online saying that those games are console bound instead of account bound, is that true?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

According to [Nintendo FAQs](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1531/~/nintendo-network-id-faq):

> Your Nintendo Network ID is tied to your software and/or additional content you have purchased and downloaded.

If you format the console setting your own NNID you won't be able to download those games because they are tied to the previous NNID.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but i found the FAQ to be confusing on this subject, it goes on to "(...)As the rights of usage for software you have purchased apply only to a single Nintendo 3DS family system, you can only register your Nintendo Network ID on one system.".
I mean, it also says the games are bound to the console, and since I saw some people say they did this formating and kept the games (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199120/can-i-keep-downloaded-games-on-a-3ds-xl-after-a-system-delete), i wanted to be sure...

Comment: They're account bound. As soon as you attach a new NNID you lose access.

Comment: @user3608304 as I said in the answer you linked, "you need the original Nintendo Network ID to redownload the previously downloaded softwares after a console format". But you cannot change that NNID without formatting the console, because downloaded content are bound to the account.

Answer (score 2):

They are not from my experience.  I have bought several games on the eShop and transferred from an old 3DS to a New 3DS and all of the games came with my profile. As long as you have the same NNID you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that they are linked to the account in question and NOT the 3DS themselves. In my line of work I often have to wipe 3DS's and sometimes I'm asked to download content from the store (that was previously purchased) on the customer's new 3DS.